# Windows 7 is missing Segoe UI Mono

Tags: windows-7, fonts

My old Windows 7 install of 2-3 years (don't remember exactly how long it's been) had the Segoe UI family of fonts, including Segoe UI Mono which I was happily using to display code and other fixed-width text.

I recently made a clean install of Windows 7 Ultimate SP1. The Segoe UI fonts appear to be mostly there, except for Segoe UI Mono, which is missing.

I can reinstall Segoe UI Mono by simply using the file from old install, but I am curious as to which application is supposed to include the Mono variant, since it must have come to my old install from somewhere. The only thing I can think of is VS2010, in this Windows install I only installed VS2012 ultimate and it uses Consolas by default.

Which applications come with Segoe UI Mono?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An incomplete version of Segoe UI Mono, [among other fonts](http://www.ascendercorp.com/developers/xna/), was included in XNA Game Studio 4.0.

Comment: @Superbest You’re welcome!